# Nasty jump to fadein div

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein

I am making a  portfolio. If people click on "Show work" it makes the div "portfolio" visible trough the following jquery code:

```
function() {
    $("#more").click(function() {
        $("#portfolio").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

It works perfectly, but the problem is, its down the page and it jumps to it.

My question is, is it possible to let it scroll downwards instead of jump?

Comment: do u want  $("#portfolio").slideDown("slow"); ??

Comment: ye something like indeed, but is that possible to combine with the fadein("slow")

Comment: slideDown will always show hidden div so no need for fadeIn

Comment: @ArunKillu but now i want to let the screen move to #portfolio. #portfolio is nearly down of the screen, any clue?

Comment: may be James Donnelly's answer is you are looking for ,can u see # symbol on url ,i suppose `more` is an a tag

Comment: @ArunKillu what do you mean by `more` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) in there to stop the `a` functioning as an anchor tag:

```
$("#more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#portfolio").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Depending on which jQuery version you're using you may also want to change that `.click()` to [`.on('click'...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), too.

Comment: Is this able to combine with a scrolldown? #portfolio is nearly at the bottom of the screen

Comment: yes use this with the above code `$(window).scrollTop($('#portfolio').offset().top);` also if u dont need a smooth scroll u can remove perventDefault and use `<a name="gotoportfolio" id="portfolio"></a>`

Comment: first one doesnt seem to work ``function() {

        $("#more").click(function(e) {

         e.preventDefault();
            $("#portfolio").slideDown("slow");
            $(window).scrollTop($('#portfolio').offset().top);
        });``
`